# fill form in R without Rselenium

Tags: r, web-scraping

I need to fill the fields month and year of the page:

[Http://www.svs.cl/institucional/mercados/entidad.php?mercado=S&rut=99588060&grupo=&tipoentidad=CSVID&row=AABaHEAAaAAAB7uAAT&vig=VI&control=svs&pestania=3](http://Http://www.svs.cl/institucional/mercados/entidad.php?mercado=S&rut=99588060&grupo=&tipoentidad=CSVID&row=AABaHEAAaAAAB7uAAT&vig=VI&control=svs&pestania=3)

By this, I have programmed the following in Rselenium and it works

```
#library
library(RSelenium)

#browser parameters
mybrowser<-remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
mybrowser$open(silent = TRUE)
mybrowser$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds =1000000)
mybrowser$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 1000000)
url<-paste("http://www.svs.cl/institucional/mercados/entidad.php?mercado=S&rut=99588060&grupo=&tipoentidad=CSVID&row=AABaHEAAaAAAB7uAAT&vig=VI&control=svs&pestania=3",sep="")

#start navigation
  mybrowser$navigate(url)
  webElem$clickElement()
  wxbox<-mybrowser$findElement(using="class","bordeInput2")
  wxbox$sendKeysToElement(list("09"))
  wxbox<-mybrowser$findElement(using="id","aa")
  wxbox$sendKeysToElement(list("2016"))
  wxbutton<-mybrowser$findElement('xpath',"//*[@id='fm']/div[2]/input")
  wxbutton$clickElement()
```

However, I'd like to see a solution using rvest or rcurl, I've tried and it does not work for me. If anyone can help me with that, I would appreciate it.

An attempt I made was

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
form <- postForm("Http://www.svs.cl/institucional/mercados/entidad.php?mercado=S&rut=99588060&grupo=&tipoentidad=CSVID&row=AABaHEAAaAAAB7uAAT&vig=VI&control=svs&pestania=3", Year = 2010, Month = 2)                                                                                                                                   
doc <- htmlParse(form)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            pkids <- xpathSApply(doc, xmlAttrs)                                                                                                                                                                    
      pkids                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
         data <- lapply(pkids)                                                                                                                                                                                                             

         tab <- readHTMLTable(data[[1]], which = 1)
```

first of all, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `POST` to the URL as follows:

```
require(rvest)
require(httr)
a <- POST("http://www.svs.cl/institucional/mercados/entidad.php",
     # Body = what you fill in the form
     body = list(mm = 09, aa = 2016),
     # query = the long URL broken into parameter
     query = list(mercado="S",
                  rut="99588060",
                  grupo="",
                  tipoentidad="CSVID",
                  row="AABaHEAAaAAAB7uAAT",
                  vig="VI",
                  control="svs",
                  pestania="3"))

read_html(a) %>% html_nodes("dd") %>% html_text %>% 
  setNames(c("Business name", "RUT"))
```

Which gives you:

```
             Business name                        RUT 
"ACE SEGUROS DE VIDA S.A."               "99588060-1"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer ^^. By chance, you will know how to get the tables on the page that you get, for example the table called "ESTADO DE SITUACIÓN FINANCIERA INDIVIDUAL - EXPRESADO EN MILES DE PESOS"

Comment: have a look at `?html_table`

Comment: Yes, I tried the follow code:   "    a<-read_html(url) 
 a<-  html_nodes(a,xpath = '//*[@id="activos_ifrs"]/table[2]')
 a<-html_table(a,fill=TRUE)   "    But I get list ()